# Amazon SQS - Disaster Recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We are evaluating Amazon SQS for one of our applications. We will be persisting some messages in SQS for a maximum of 10 hours a day (one of our 'consumers' can only process between 7am and 9pm).

It appears that persisted messages are distributed across multiple availability zones in the same geographical region. Is there a way to achieve replication across regions in SQS? I read Amazon's white paper on DR and it has no mention about SQS.

Comment: Hi Sayak any idea on how you solved it ?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is each time you write into SQS in your region, you also write into SQS in another region. Here are my suggestions:

1. You would have to do that programmatically, and depending on your requirements you may have to implement a two phase commit.
2. Alternatively, you use SNS to publish your messages, but configure the SNS subscriptions to write to SQS queues across regions.

Bear in mind that AWS availability zones are already actually geographically distributed, about 50 miles away from each other, I believe.

If this was my project, I would follow option 2. Take a look at this AWS document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html

Basically, what you do is instead of publishing directly to SQS, you create an SNS topic in each region. Each of those topics has SQS subscriptions in both regions as well.

When a message is published to SNS in either region, SNS will automatically publish to both SQS subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We also looked at the SNS approach, but the fact that we have to manually delete the messages from both SQS instances was a deal breaker. Also, I work for a financial organization which requires DR data centers to be at least 250mi apart.

Comment: So, maybe SQS is not what you want. Have you considered ActiveMQ master-slave configuration ?

Comment: We are looking at Kafka. SQS was being considered because of the cost benefits.

Comment: this approach will unnecessary complicated things as you have to be in sync with message consumptions too for both the regions.. So you consumer should read the messages from both the regions simultaneously and then consider similar to a transaction block to process both messages for same purpose. Does not sound good to me.

Comment: Apart considerations already done by others, in option 2 you are only moving the problem to SNS. If a region fail, SNS in that region will do too.

Answer (score 2):

Each SQS queue is currently limited to a single region. Each SQS queue is replicated across multiple Availability Zones though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this. I am looking to have the possibility of some sort of a master-slave setup across AWS regions. But so far what I've read, that doesn't seem to be feasible without the application performing the DeleteMessageRequest manually on both queues.

Answer (score 0):

SQS is replicated redundantly across multiple AZ's.

The only evidence I could find for this is: https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Security_and_reliability

> redundant Availability Zones (AZs), so that no single computer,
> network, or AZ failure can make messages inaccessible

the key part being "redundant AZs". I had felt "make messages" to be ambiguous (do they mean any or all messages?) but the rest of the sentence resolves this.

Concerning cross-region bridging, SQS does not allow this:

> Q: Can I share messages between queues in different regions?
>
> No. Each Amazon SQS message queue is independent within each region.

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Service_access_and_regions

However, Amazon MQ does permit cross region message propagation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/network-of-brokers.html